how to get "g-recaptcha_response" from cookies?
i need get "g-recaptcha_response" for next requests. and found this:
Google reCaptcha - How to get g-recaptcha-response - without FORM TAG
enter image description here
but its not python and how should i get "g-recaptcha_response" value from cookies?
My example code:
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/php/getReCaptchaResponse.php'
response = requests.post(url)

< SOME CODE FOR EXTRACTING reCAPTCHA RESPONSE VALUE >

print(" g-recaptcha_response HERE ")

Some part of site source:
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="text-center m-2">
                                <div id="send-message-response">
                                    <p>Waiting for Google's <a href='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/'>reCaptcha</a> to load.
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div  id='recaptcha'
                                    data-sitekey=" 6Leeuq0UAAAAAHJIeHS-tjb4hRIlcCDTizIru6cv " 
                                    class='g-recaptcha'
                                    data-name='g-recaptcha-response'
                                    data-callback='sendTest'
                                    data-size='invisible'>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        
                        <p class="test-box-sml">By entering your mobile number, you agree to receive messages to the phone number provided for the purposes of testing the BulkSMS platform.</p>
                        <p class="test-box-sml">BulkSMS takes data protection seriously. We only collect your personal information and company data that is necessary for us to provide you with our messaging services. For more information on how we process your data, please take a look at our <a href="/company/data-processing-and-privacy-policy.htm">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
                                                
                    </div>
        
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </section>
    
</main>

<!--[if lte IE 9]><script charset='UTF-8' src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaOnload&render=explicit"></script><![endif]-->
<script charset='UTF-8' src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaOnload&render=explicit" async defer></script>

Thanks for everything...

captcha may use JavaScript but requests can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

better show real URL in question (not in comments) - so we could see it in browser and test it in code

Hey guys! i fixed it by using random user agents. Thanks...
